# Need a query like UNION, but returns data in the corresponding column aliases of 2nd and nth queries, not the first query columns/aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider this UNION of two (or more) queries:

```
    SELECT activity AS activity1, completion AS status1, date_end AS date1
    FROM activities
    WHERE (
        matter LIKE '%JR161167' 
        AND activity LIKE '1.1 %' 
        AND DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , date_end ) <120 
    )
UNION
    SELECT activity AS activity2, completion AS status2, date_end AS date2
    FROM activities
    WHERE (
        matter LIKE '%JR161167' 
        AND activity LIKE '1.2 %' 
        AND DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , date_end ) <120 
    )
```

The activity column will contain a variable string value, but the string will reliably be prepended with `1.1` or `1.2` or `1.3` all the way to `1.9`.

The matter column is also a string, but will reliably be appended with an account number that resembles `JR161167`.

I want to query all records that have date_end from within the past 120 days (that's the `DATEFIFF` part), matching the specified account number (JR161167), but where the activity field contains any and all substrings "1.*n*".

Using the UNION returns the right data from a single table, "activities", but there seems to be no way around heading the result set under the columns or aliases of the very first query. Instead, I want something like:

```
activity1             status1    date1     activity2 status2          date2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.1 Step 1 begins...  Incomplete 2017-4-16 1.2       Step 2 begins... Incomplete 2017-4-30
```

Instead, my query stacks all results, no matter if they contain 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc., under one alias column heading, `activity1`. Same thing with the date and completion field data, it doesn't bother nicely sorting into the corresponding date1, date2, etc., or status1, status2, etc.

I recently read an example that looks something like this, which looks like the logic I want to implement, and I wonder if anyone can understand its intent and help me formulate the right query:

```
SELECT date_end
IF( WHERE description LIKE '1.1 %') AS date1,
IF( WHERE description LIKE '1.2 %') AS date2`
FROM activities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5b4/3)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a1.*, a2.*
FROM (
    SELECT matter, activity, completion, date_end
    FROM activities
    WHERE 
        matter LIKE '%JR16116' 
        AND activity = '1.1' 
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_end) <120
) a1
JOIN (
    SELECT matter, activity, completion, date_end
    FROM activities
    WHERE 
        matter LIKE '%JR16116' 
        AND activity = '1.2' 
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_end) <120
) a2
    ON a1.matter = a2.matter
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5b4/3/0)**:

```
|  matter | activity | completion |   date_end |  matter | activity | completion |   date_end |
|---------|----------|------------|------------|---------|----------|------------|------------|
| JR16116 |      1.1 |          1 | 2017-04-22 | JR16116 |      1.2 |          1 | 2017-04-23 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
    -- other way without sub request but clean join

SELECT 
    a.matter, a.activity, a.completion, a.date_end
    ,a2.activity, a2.completion, a2.date_end
    -- ,a3.activity, a3.completion, a3.date_end
FROM activities a
JOIN activities a2
    ON (
        a.matter = a2.matter
        AND a2.activity = '1.2' 
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), a2.date_end) <120
    )
-- JOIN activities a3
--  ON (
--      a.matter = a3.matter
--      AND a3.activity = '1.3' 
--      AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), a3.date_end) <120
--  )

WHERE 
    a.matter LIKE '%JR16116' 
    AND a.activity = '1.1' 
    AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), a.date_end) <120
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5b4/3/1)**:

```
|  matter | activity | completion |   date_end | activity | completion |   date_end |
|---------|----------|------------|------------|----------|------------|------------|
| JR16116 |      1.1 |          1 | 2017-04-22 |      1.2 |          1 | 2017-04-23 |
```

Comment: Very nice! JOIN, not UNION. This is the key piece of my project. It's definitely working.

Comment: @TARKUS you're welcome, I've added a 2nd way to do the query, with join like you should use them ;)

Comment: your second way is even more manageable, because I have to multiply the JOINS X 9 (steps 1.1 - 1.9), and loop through thousands of 'matter' or account numbers. And again, the query is working. Thank you!